# Does the CSS block attribute affect HTML well-formedness?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

An HTML `<body>` element can only contain block elements such as `<p>`. If I declare an inline element such as `<span>` to be `display: block` using CSS does that make the following HTML well-formed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span style="display: block;">Hi!</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can always use http://validator.w3.org/ to check

Comment: Try avoid terms like "well-formed" with HTML. Well-formedness is an XML concept. As XML, your sample is well-formed regardless of the value of the "style" attribute. "Valid" or "Conforming" are appropriate terms for measuring the correctness of HTML. - And CSS *never* changes the validity of HTML.

Comment: Maybe so, but he is specifying an XHTML-strict DTD there, so technically it *IS* xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<span>` is an inline element and not a valid direct child of `<body>`. The CSS `display` attribute does not change that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check to see if [it validated](http://validator.w3.org/check) (it doesn't)?  The specifications for XHTML and HTML only apply to themselves, they don't cross boundaries with CSS specifications much.  Thus, there won't be anywhere in the definition that checks the value of the style attribute for a certain CSS property in order to validate a document.